# Unmanaged objects in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my Swift, iOS I may override the JSQ method like:

`override func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>! {
        //CODE
    }`

My confusion is, what do I return as the Unmanaged?

Answer (score 0):

> My confusion is, what do I return as the Unmanaged?

[`Unmanaged`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unmanaged) is a generic type used to contain object references that aren't managed by the runtime. Exactly what you should return depends on what method you're trying to replace. You haven't told us what that method is, so we have no way to tell you what the method is expected to return, other than (obviously) the fact that it returns *something* that's wrapped in an `Unmanaged` value.

**Note:** You're really not *overriding* the method in question, you're just arranging for your own code to be called instead. If you wanted to *override* a method, you'd instead subclass the class you're trying to modify.